# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'gps_id' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

When I call this function show error: Cannot read property 'gps_id' of undefined

ts code

```
  contrat: Contrat[];
  gpss: GPS[];
  homeboxp: HomeboxP[];
  sensors: Sensors[];
  homebox: Homebox[];

getProductName(productid: string) {
    const [filteredProd] = this.contrat.filter(pt => pt.contrat_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdG] = this.gpss.filter(pt => pt.gps_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdhbp] = this.homeboxp.filter(pt => pt.homeboxpackage_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdh] = this.homebox.filter(pt => pt.homebox_id === productid);
    const [filteredProds] = this.sensors.filter(pt => pt.sensors_id === productid);

    if  (productid === filteredProd.contrat_id) {
      console.log(filteredProd.contratdesc)
      return filteredProd.contratdesc;

    } else if (productid === filteredProdG.gps_id) {
      console.log(filteredProdG.gps_serial)
      return filteredProdG.gps_serial;
    } else if (productid === filteredProdhbp.homeboxpackage_id) {
      console.log(filteredProdhbp.sensor_serial)
      return filteredProdhbp.sensor_serial;

    } else if (productid === filteredProdh.homebox_id) {
      console.log(filteredProdh.serial_number)
      return filteredProdh.serial_number;

    } else if (productid === filteredProds.sensors_id) {
      console.log(filteredProds.sensor_serial)
      return filteredProds.sensor_serial;
    }
  }
```

html code:

```
<tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products; let i=index">
  <td>{{getProductName(item.product_id)}}</td> 
</tr>
```

Can you suggest me what is the problem in this code?

EDIT:
I have this html form

```
<form [formGroup]="myform" (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
       <tbody>
              <tr class="group" *ngFor="let item of products;">
                <td>
                  <div>
                    {{item.product_type_id}}
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{item.product_id}}</td>
               </tr>
          </tbody>
    <form>
```

I have this products in ts code:  `this.products = this.ps.getProduct();` that getall my product. Product have this property

```
export class Products {
    product_id: number;
    product_type_id: number;
    prodcttype: ProductType[];}
```

service product

```
  private products: Products[] = [];
  getProduct() {
    return this.products;
  }
```

product_id are id of my product, example,

```
product_id: 1 --> HP
product_id: 2 --> Sensor 1
product_id: 3 --> GPS1
```

These products I get from ws, 
service gps

```
this.wsg.getAllGpss().subscribe(
  gpss => {
    this.gpss = gpss;
  }
);
```

Class:

```
export class GPS {
    gps_serial: string;
    gps_imei: string;
    gps_id: string;}
```

service homeboxp

```
this.wshbp.homeboxPGetAll().subscribe(
  homeboxp => {
    this.homeboxp = homeboxp;
  }
);
```

Class:

```
export class HomeboxP {
    sensors_id: string[];
    sensor_serial: string[];
    homeboxpackage_id : string;}
```

service sensors

```
this.wss.getAllSensors().subscribe(
  sensors => {
    this.sensors = sensors;
  }
);
```

Class:

```
export class Sensors {
     sensors_id: string;
    sensor_serial: string;}
```

Now, that I want is, when I put product_id: 2 I want to display in html gps_serial:Sensor 1, this product is in sensors. So, in this case, product_id is the same as sensor_id, also  when I put product_id: 3 I want to display in html  gps_serial:GPS1, this product is in gpss. So, in this case, product_id is the same as gps_id

I try to use this function:

```
getProductName(productid: string) {
    const [filteredProd] = this.contrat.filter(pt => pt.contrat_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdG] = this.gpss.filter(pt => pt.gps_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdhbp] = this.homeboxp.filter(pt => pt.homeboxpackage_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdh] = this.homebox.filter(pt => pt.homebox_id === productid);
    const [filteredProds] = this.sensors.filter(pt => pt.sensors_id === productid);

    if  (productid === filteredProd.contrat_id) {
      console.log(filteredProd.contratdesc)
      return filteredProd.contratdesc;

    } else if (productid === filteredProdG.gps_id) {
      console.log(filteredProdG.gps_serial)
      return filteredProdG.gps_serial;
    } else if (productid === filteredProdhbp.homeboxpackage_id) {
      console.log(filteredProdhbp.sensor_serial)
      return filteredProdhbp.sensor_serial;

    } else if (productid === filteredProdh.homebox_id) {
      console.log(filteredProdh.serial_number)
      return filteredProdh.serial_number;

    } else if (productid === filteredProds.sensors_id) {
      console.log(filteredProds.sensor_serial)
      return filteredProds.sensor_serial;
    }
  }
```

and in html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myform" (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
       <tbody>
              <tr class="group" *ngFor="let item of products;">
                <td>{{getProductName(item.product_id)}}</td>
               </tr>
          </tbody>
    <form>
```

Comment: What is the result of `this.gpss.filter(pt => pt.gps_id === productid);`? Or is this the line where the error is occuring?

Comment: there is not enough information to answer your question so the only hint I can give you is that either `pt` or `filteredProdG` is undefined

Comment: @andrew In this line   <td>{{getProductName(item.product_id)}}</td> Look edit code. Thanx

Comment: @tomichel I edit my post. Thnx

Comment: Is the type of gpss equal to GPS[]?

Comment: @andrew Yes, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is with the `getProductName` function.

Have you tried checking to make sure the object exists before comparing to it? E.g.:

```
getProductName(productid: string) {
    const [filteredProd] = this.contrat.filter(pt => pt.contrat_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdG] = this.gpss.filter(pt => pt.gps_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdhbp] = this.homeboxp.filter(pt => pt.homeboxpackage_id === productid);
    const [filteredProdh] = this.homebox.filter(pt => pt.homebox_id === productid);
    const [filteredProds] = this.sensors.filter(pt => pt.sensors_id === productid);

    // Checks for `filteredProd` existing before checking
    if  (typeof filteredProd != 'undefined' && productid === filteredProd.contrat_id) {
        console.log(filteredProd.contratdesc)
        return filteredProd.contratdesc;
    } else if (typeof filteredProdG != 'undefined' && productid === filteredProdG.gps_id) {
        console.log(filteredProdG.gps_serial)
        return filteredProdG.gps_serial;
    } else if (typeof filteredProdhbp != 'undefined' && productid === filteredProdhbp.homeboxpackage_id) {
        console.log(filteredProdhbp.sensor_serial)
        return filteredProdhbp.sensor_serial;
    } else if (typeof filteredProdh != 'undefined' && productid === filteredProdh.homebox_id) {
        console.log(filteredProdh.serial_number)
        return filteredProdh.serial_number;
    } else if (typeof filteredProds != 'undefined' && productid === filteredProds.sensors_id) {
        console.log(filteredProds.sensor_serial)
        return filteredProds.sensor_serial;
    }
}
```

Note how each time it checks to see if the filtered element exists before it checks it. As a thought question: What is the value of the `x`?

`[x] = []`

Comment: Thank you so much, this work good. Now I can see in console only this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined